# Is there a (free/Open Source) tool that neatly displays changes in a file system/tree compared to a previously saved meta image of it? (Windows)

Tags: windows, gratis

Very difficult to describe in one sentence (title) what I'm looking for. Basically I'd like to have the following use cycle:

1. Run the application to create a meta image (in some form) of a file tree (e.d. a drive or just any folder). That meta image would be a file containing meta information about the tree structure (file paths) and some additional data like modification dates or sizes.
2. At a later point in time run the application and compare the current state (or a newly created meta image) to the old image and get a neat browsable UI showing which files have been deleted, created or modified in between.

Basically it comes down to the following three features:

- Create meta images of file trees
- Compare meta images
- Neatly display meta image difference data

I'm on Windows, but familiar with UNIX tools and I have an MinGW/MSYS environment installed. One could maybe create such a meta image using `find` or `ls` and some magic to add metadata. One could maybe just `diff` two such dumps, but I'd expect the result to need more processing in order to be really helpful for the user.

Comment: run a dirs /s or a powershell command that capture a dir tree to a file. Then upload it in git e.g. in a Github Repo and you have all the diff capabilities in Git using any Diff tool.

Comment: Not free, so comment, not answer. I pay $45/year for unlimited backup from one PC ***plus*** external drives. I am currently backing up about 7tB, so it's a good price. They have also introduced [version history](https://help.backblaze.com/hc/en-us/articles/360035247494-Version-History-FAQ). Check it out, it might be useful, and even justify a dollar a week for backup peace of mind.

Answer (score 0):

This might be too complicated for you, but it springs to mind immediately.

As a professional programmer, I often have to do that with directories of source code. We use a [Version Control System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control).

Whenever code is stable, we "commit" it to version control, which takes a snapshot. Then we code some more, and the VCS makes it easy to see which files, and which parts of them, have changed.

I recommend [Tortoise SVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/)

Comment: I'd say the chances were high from your pov that it might be too complicated for me, but coincidentally I do use Git on a regular basis. I have no experience with SVN, though. I feel a VCS would be a bit overkill (and steal too much of my time), because it diffs all the files instead of checking only existance and mod dates. At least Git does that. Is there a config in SVN that lets it ignore what exactly changed in the files?

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of a Version Control System, but automatic, would be a [Versioning file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versioning_file_system).

***IF***, you can find one for Windows.

That Wikipedia page which  referenced above says:

Microsoft Windows

- Shadow Copy - is a feature introduced by Microsoft with Windows Server 2003. Shadow Copy allows for taking manual or automatic backup copies or snapshots of a file or folder on a specific volume at a specific point in time.
- RollBack Rx - Allows snapshots of disk partitions to be taken. Each snapshot contains only the differences between previous snapshots, and take only seconds to create. Can be reliably used to keep a Windows OS stable and/or protected from malware.
- GoBack (discontinued) - The GoBack software for Windows from Symantec enables reversion of files, directories or disks to previous states. It can record a maximum of 8GB in changes, and temporarily stops recording each change in the event of high I/O activity.
- Versomatic - Versomatic software by Acertant automatically tracks file changes and preemptively archives a copy of a file before it is modified.

Disclaimer: I have used versioning file systems, but not on Windows. You would have to research these yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Three years later ... if you can code, then you can knock up a Python script to do what you want.

If https://www.itechtics.com/monitor-system-file-registry-changes/ doesn't help, then look at https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/ or possibly https://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html